# Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature is not recognized in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, environment-variables

When I try to run Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature windows throws ''Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

I am running windows 10.

There is no environment variable called Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature. Should I add it, and if so, what path should I add?

Comment: 1.The Get-WindowsOptionalFeature cmdlet requires PowerShell 3.0.
2.This cmdlet must run with elevated rights. Right-click the Windows PowerShell 3.0 console while holding the CTRL key, and select Run As Administrator from the action menu

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command you are trying to run cannot be ran in Windows Command Prompt, you need to run it in [Windows Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/enable-windowsoptionalfeature?view=win10-ps).

Comment: I'm running PowerShell Core as an administration and I'm facing the same problem. Is there another possible cause?